# Swift: UICollectionView with dynamic and static cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've got a few collectionviewcells being created from an array. What I want is a static cell that sits at the very end of all these cells.

so not matter how many cells I add, this particular cell stays at the very end

Also if its impossible to do this, what ideas do you have to accomplish what I'm trying

Thank you so much. I really appreciate any answers you offer

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes this is absolutely possible.

In `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int` you should always return 1 more than the number of items you have.

In `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` you should check to see if indexPath.row is equal to the number of items you have. If it is, configure that particular cell to have a + sign.

**Common Mistake Below**

Be sure that for this last cell you do NOT make a call accessing the same Array you use for tags.

For example, if your array of tags looks like this:

```
var myItems = ["Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3"]
```

Then the following code is **erroneous**:

```
var titleToDisplayOnCell = myItems[indexPath.row] // Don't do this!
```

This is because for the cell where the + sign should be displayed, row is 3 and there is no object at myItems[3] -- that's beyond the bounds of the array, which is 0 to 2 inclusive.

Comment: What makes an `UICollectionViewCell` a static cell? Where does one set that? (I know the distinction between "Dynamic Prototypes" and "Static Cells" for `UITableView`s, but that does not seem to match here.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is definitely possible. My preferred way to accomplish this is to use two separate sections in the collection view:

```
func numberOfSections() -> Int { 
    return 2
}


func numberOfItemsInSection(_ section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return array.count
    } else if section == 1 { 
        return 1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}


func cellForItemAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell? {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
      // set up the standard cell, using the data from the army
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
      //set up the "+" cell
    }
}
```

The other way you can achieve this same goal is to just use one section, declare the size of the collection view as being the size of the array + 1, and setting up the extra cell in an if statement in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method, but you will find it will lead to a lot more complications with the extra math. It is usually safer to keep cells using different data in different sections if at all possible

Comment: I agree with sanche. However, I would avoid the else if indexPath.section == 1, in favor of an else statement. You only have two collectionView cells. Therefore, it can only be 1 or the other.

Comment: the problem with using sections for this is in case I am using Supplementary views to display section headers, in that case, my "+" cell will always appear oddly in a section with it's own header.